# supply a vector to "classes" of dataframe

Tags: r

You know how you can supply a vector of names to a data frame to change the col or row names of a dataframe.  Is there a similar method to supply a vector of names that alters the class of each column in a dataframe?  You can do this when you read in a dataframe with read.table using colClasses.  What about if the dataframe is created inside R?

```
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5))
str(DF)  #all numeric modes

names(DF) <- c("A", "A2", "B", "B2", "Z") #I want something like this for classes
some_classes_function_like_names(DF) <- c(rep("character", 3), rep("factor", 2))

#I can do it like this but this seems inefficient 
DF[, 1:3] <- lapply(DF[, 1:3], as.character)
DF[, 4:5] <- lapply(DF[, 4:5], as.factor)

str(DF)
```

EDIT:  I changed sapply above to lapply as sapply doesn't make sense.

EDIT 2: If there's a way to write a user defined function that would suffice as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems `class(x) <- "factor"` doesn't work and neither does `as(x, "factor")`, so I don't know of a direct way of doing what you want.

...But a slightly more explicit way is:

```
# Coerces data.frame columns to the specified classes
colClasses <- function(d, colClasses) {
    colClasses <- rep(colClasses, len=length(d))
    d[] <- lapply(seq_along(d), function(i) switch(colClasses[i], 
        numeric=as.numeric(d[[i]]), 
        character=as.character(d[[i]]), 
        Date=as.Date(d[[i]], origin='1970-01-01'), 
        POSIXct=as.POSIXct(d[[i]], origin='1970-01-01'), 
        factor=as.factor(d[[i]]),
        as(d[[i]], colClasses[i]) ))
    d
}

# Example usage
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5))
DF2 <- colClasses(DF, c(rep("character", 3), rep("factor", 2)))
str(DF2)

DF3 <- colClasses(DF, 'Date')
str(DF3)
```

A couple of things: you can add more cases as needed. And the first line of the function allows you to call with a single class name. The last "default" case of the `switch` calls the `as` function and you mileage might vary.

Comment: @ Tommy I was hoping for the answer "You dope there's already a base function that does that easily".  Your functions works well.  I'm going to throw it into my .First() as a convenience function for myself.  I'm actually a little surprised the R-core team hasn't already implemented something like this especially since it seems to be a part of read.table.  Thank you.

Comment: @Tyler I shared your surprise.  I have long sought a base function to do just this, and usually take some ad hoc approach on the fly.  It would be great if the R-core team would consider this in base.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
toCls <- function(x, cls) do.call(paste("as", cls, sep = "."), list(x))
replace(DF,, Map(toCls, DF, cls))
```

Second example. Also try this example (which allows `NA` to be used for any column whose class is not to be changed).  We load the zoo package since it provides a version of `as.Date` that has a default origin and we define our own `as.POSIXct2` to likewise avoid having to otherwise specify the origin.

```
library(zoo) # supplies alternate as.Date with a default origin
as.NA <- identity
as.POSIXct2 <- function(x) as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1970-01-01")

cls2 <- c("character", "Date", NA, "factor", "POSIXct2")
replace(DF,, Map(toCls, DF, cls2))
```

Note that its only when converting numbers to `"Date"` or `"POSIXct"` that there are origin considerations and when converting character strings such as `"2000-01-01"` no origin would need to be specified in any case so for such situations we would not need to load zoo and we would not need our own version of `as.POSIXct` .

EDIT: Added another example.