# How to change values in data frame by column class in R

Tags: r, class, frame, apply

I've got a frame with a set of different variables - integers, factors, logicals - and I would like to recode all of the "NAs" as a numeric across the whole dataset while preserving the underlying variable class. For example:

```
frame <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(10), "y" = rep("A", 10))
frame[6,] <- NA

dat <- as.data.frame(apply(frame,2, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x)== TRUE, -9, x) ))
dat
str(dat)
```

However, here the integers turn into factors; when I include as.numeric(x) in the apply() function, this introduces errors. Thanks for any and all thoughts on how to deal with this.

Comment: You want your factor column to have `-9` as a new level aswell? You have to either pick that or turn the factors into numerics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` returns a matrix of type character. `as.data.frame` turns this into factors by default. Instead, you could do

```
dat <- as.data.frame(lapply(frame, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), -9, x) ) )
```

Comment: This turns all factors into numerics since you're replacing a factor with a numeric.

Comment: Good point, @Molx. If the column classes should be retained, one could add `dat <- replace(dat,, Map(function(x, cls) do.call(paste("as", cls, sep = "."), list(x)), dat, sapply(frame, class)))`. ([via](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214819/supply-a-vector-to-classes-of-dataframe))